# Enqueuing function to run after all events on current form are handled

Tags: javascript, event-loop, web-standards

I have a form with a `formdata` event handler that updates a field of the `FormData` if a certain state is found in the DOM. After the form submission, the DOM needs to be changed, but the `formdata` event handler should still observe the old state. Currently, I achieve this by using `setTimeout(() => {/*...*/}, 0)` in a `submit` event handler on the same form, because this will enqueue the function to run later - hopefully, after the `formdata` event is handled. My question is: Is this behavior guaranteed, and if not, is there a specification-backed way to accomplish this behavior?

In the [specification of event loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model), the first step for choosing what work to do next is described as:

> Let taskQueue be one of the event loop's task queues, chosen in an implementation-defined manner [...]

The oldest task from this chosen queue is then run later on. This would mean, that if functions scheduled with `setTimeout` are in the same task queue as the event handlers and if the `formdata` event handler is scheduled before the submit handler is actually run, I would definitely be safe - I cannot find any evidence for that though. From the [documentation of the `formdata` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/formdata_event) ("fires after the entry list representing the form's data is constructed") and the fact, that the `formdata` handler is run after the `submit` handler, I would even assume the contrary to be true - but that is not what I observed with the approach described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is quite correct, and you are right that `setTimeout(fn, 0)` may not always fire after a "related" event: it is indeed very possible that these events are fired from two different tasks, very unlikely they'll use the *timer* [task sources](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source), and you correctly identified the bit that would make the event loop "possibly" select a task from an other task source.

However in this exact case, **you are safe**.

The `submit` event and the `formdata` one are fired from the same "task"*.

If you look at the form [submit algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-form-submit), you can see that the submit event is directly [fired](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) at step 6.5, instead of being wrapped in a task that would get [queued](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) like it's often the case.

> Let *shouldContinue* be the result of [firing an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) named `submit` at *form* [...]

Then in the same algorithm, without any *in parallel* or anything implying asynchronicity, we have the step 8 that says

> Let *entry list* be the result of [constructing the entry list](https://Let%20entry%20list%20be%20the%20result%20of%20constructing%20the%20entry%20list%20with%20form,%20submitter,%20and%20encoding.) with *form*, *submitter*, and *encoding*.

And in this [constructing the entry list](https://Let%20entry%20list%20be%20the%20result%20of%20constructing%20the%20entry%20list%20with%20form,%20submitter,%20and%20encoding.) algorithm, at the step 7, we have the call to

> [Fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) named `formdata` at *form* [...]

once again without any asynchronicity allowed.

So we can be sure that these events will fire without anything else in between (apart microtasks), and that your timer callback from the `submit` event will fire after the `formdata` callback, even two `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks scheduled in the same frame (that are also "*synchronous*" for the event loop) won't be able to interleave there:

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", e => {
  console.log("submit");
});
document.forms[0].addEventListener("formdata", e => {
  console.log("formdata");
});
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log("rAF 1");
  document.forms[0].querySelector("button").click();
});
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log("rAF 2");
});
```

```html
<form target="target">
  <input value="foo" name="bar">
  <button>
  submit
  </button>
</form>
<iframe name="target"></iframe>
```

*<sub>Technically it does not even need to be from a task per se, you can very well force these events to fire from a microtask or a resize event callback etc.)</sub>

Comment: Great, I didn't know that dispatching (as in `dispatchEvent` even. or in the text for "firing an event") means running things synchronously and thought that "dispatching" always implied pushing to the queue (I now read the right paragraph of `dispatchEvent` in the mdn too). To be clear, it doesn't really matter whether the submission event is started from the queue or fired directly, because all the action only starts _whenever_ the submission is started, right? In any way, exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes the whole submission is executed as one block, so indeed it doesn't matter from where it was started.